# Combining Data Sets to run Monte Carlo Simulations

Tags: python, montecarlo

(newbie) I am having trouble trying to combine 2 dataframes to help predict fantasy football scores.

I have one dataset that has each players projections and STD. then another set of randomly created fantasy football teams.

I am trying to run each team (1000) through a monte carlo sim based on my projections/std and then rank them by different criteria (max, correlation, ceiling, etc).

How do i get the monte carlo sim to calculate these for each row (team).

[Projections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gkwg.png)
[Teams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZ45M.png)